# Saving a screenshot to Server using JQuery and ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, html2canvas

Essentially what I want to do is save a screenshot of a web page to a server and NOT  on a client's machine.

I have used html2canvas to save a div to a local directory, and can I have also managed to save a canvas tag to a server, however I want to be able to save a div tag server-side.

The following allows the ability to save server side by using a Handler.

```
$(function () {
    $("#add_button").click(function () {
        var image = document.getElementById("myCanvas").toDataURL("image/png");

        image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

        $.get("Handler.ashx", { imageData: image }, function (data) {
            alert("Saved!");
        });
    });
});
```

The following creates a screenshot image of the form tag and saves it locally.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
        html2canvas($("#form1"), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                //theCanvas = canvas;
                //document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
                    saveAs(blob, "Dashboard.png");
                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Basically, I want to save a screenshot image of a "form" tag to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Code that you can print the page as PDF using javascript

```
<asp:Button ID="imgBtnPrint" OnClientClick="javascript:window.print();" runat="Server" Text="Print" />
```